# How to authenticate as a Craft user with a frontend tool like Next.js, Nuxt.js, or create-react-app?

Tags: users, admin, authentication, app, headless

We're looking to use Craft CMS as an application platform (handling content storage, user authentication, etc) for an upcoming project while leveraging something like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) on the front-end.

Here's a very basic gist of how the application will work:

- A user can sign into (or create) an account
- An authenticated user can create a job post

We'd love to use a frontend tool like Next.js, Nuxt.js or create-react-app. If we use this what's the best way to authenticate to the Craft back-end since the front-end and back-end are separated?

Comment: I'd love to know if you get anywhere with this I have the same issue. My current approach for login is using the element API to return me the csrf token and then using the normal login form in a Vue template.